# Is Webpack required to transpile SCSS into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, webpack

I'm using webpack to compile my scss with a config, looks a little something like this:

```
...
loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      //working, but perhaps not most modern way of autoprefixing
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }
  ],
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")]
  }
...
```

This takes my sass and turns it into JavaScript. In so doing, I lose browsersync's ability to inject CSS code without refreshing a page. Is there a way to make webpack compile into a normal CSS file, or is CSS delivered via JavaScript just the Webpack way of things?

Comment: You can use something like [compass](http://compass-style.org/) to compile scss into css.

Comment: @VladimirM Yeah, I know there are a lot of options to do the task, however my thought was to consolidate my deployment tasks using Webpack, so I'm trying to figure out the right approach, if this is something configurable, or if this JS approach is just the way it is done via Webpack. Cheers.